# How to process a file in a Azure Blob storage on a perticular business day using a spring Batch

Tags: azure, cron, azure-blob-storage

I have a situation where i have to process a file in a Azure Blob storage(which will be kept by some process on a particular day) using a spring batch. Now the requirement is i have to only process that file on that particular business day and not on the other day.So if i am creating a scheduler/Cron to call the batch on that day it may not work , because in the cron i have to give a particular time when it will trigger the batch.Now if the file does not arrive on that particular  time to the blob storage the cron will not find the file to process.

Is there any file watcher in the Azure utility which i can use to check of the file arrives and then i can call the batch.
Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have an idea about it. I think I can use 'blob trigger' to record a statement if the target file has uploaded, and before the cron executed, check the statement first to avoid finding no file to process. Here's a [document](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6361/process-blob-files-automatically-using-an-azure-function-with-blob-trigger/) describing how to use blob trigger to copy file to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tiny indicated, you can [create an Azure function and use Azure blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=java#example) to monitor new come in files. Once the function is triggered, you can call your spring batch(by some URL exposed by your app) in your Azure function code to handle this file.

If you don't want to code, you can use [Azure Logic app and blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger) to monitor new come in files and call your Spring batch.